# How can I fetch xml POST?

Tags: javascript, xml, fetch

I am working on REST API which is xml 
The tutorial is 
https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_get_started_tutorial_part_1.htm
and the request body is,

```
<tsRequest>
    <credentials name="user-name" password="password">
        <site contentUrl="my-site-name" />
    </credentials>
</tsRequest>
```

I am trying,

```js
const requestionOptions = {
  method: "POST",
  body: '<tsRequest>
    <credentials name="myusername" password="mypassword">
        <site contentUrl="my-site-name" />
    </credentials>
</tsRequest>'
}
const baseUrl = 'example.com'
export function userLogin(username, password){
  fetch(baseUrl, requestOptions)
    .then(res => {console.log(res)})
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
}
```

Before running this script, I checked the code in dev console, dev console throws error on `requestOPtion` that uncaught syntax. How can I create fetch call with this XML?

Comment: Your constant name is 'requestionOptions'
Did you meant to initialize it  as 'requestOption' which is being used in the .fetch function?

Comment: @AbidSulemanAhmed good catch. I fixed the typo

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const requestOption = {
  method: POST
  body: `<tsRequest>
    <credentials name="myusername" password="mypassword">
        <site contentUrl="my-site-name" />
    </credentials>
</tsRequest>`
}
const baseUrl = 'example.com'
export function userLogin(username, password){
  fetch(baseUrl, requestOption)
    .then(res => {console.log(res)})
    .catch(err => {console.log(err)})
}
```

"Single Quotes" ' do not support multiline the way you are trying to do it. You need to use "Back Tick" ` to do multiline ie "Template Literals". Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Also, it looks like you have a variable spelling error? ie requestionOptions should be requestOption?

Comment: I suspect my solution will only solve your immediate issue.